# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/'

Tags: php, wordpress

My website was working fine but then it started showing this error
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' on line 12` in this `php` phrase:

```
<?php
/**
 * Loads the WordPress environment and template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {

    $wp_did_header = true;

    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . / wp-load.php );

    wp();

    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . / template-loader.php );

}
```

if I remove the `/` it started saying that unable to load `wp-load.php`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your website was working fine, then all of a sudden, it broke?.. You carefully omit what you had done to get these errors. Also, did you actually look at line 12 and google require_once ? Technically it isn't a function so you don't need the brackets.

Comment: Note: you should use ``DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`` instead of ``/`` if you change the OS this could cause errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `require_once` expect an string.

```
if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {

    $wp_did_header = true;
    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
    wp();
    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );

}
```

Comment: Empty space after the directory separator...

Comment: @Havelock thanks mate, I didn't notice it

Comment: @jycr753 thanks this works like magic. :D but I wonder why people down voted this question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do that :

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php');
```

Same thing here :

```
require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php');
```